# Is it possible to save message received by ipcRenderer in electron to be used outside of the scope of the ipcRenderer?

Tags: vue.js, electron, electron-builder

This is the barebones of the code that I have. Was wondering if anyone knew a better approach than what I am 'trying' to do... I assumed that I was having trouble due to my minimal experience with block, function and global scoping however i feel like i have tried every combination of let, var, const, etc...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.s this script is running on the front end of my application. The message is being sent from a file called background.js and runs when electron is spinning up the application that takes data collected from my os

```
<script>
    
    const ipcRend = require('electron').ipcRenderer
    var savedData = null
    
    ipcRend.on('channel', (event, data) => {
    savedData = data
    console.log(data) // outputs as expected
    console.log(savedData) // outputs as expected
    })

    console.log(savedData)// undefined
    
    </script>
```

Comment: the last console.log() is called before the event is received from main process. it is not clear what exactly are you trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is not only related to scopes, but also to code flow. This is the order in which your commands are executed. In your case, `console.log(savedData)` is executed before your listener sets the variable.

Why? Because your code does not wait until it receives the `"channel"` event. Executing `ipcRenderer.on (event, callback);` only *registers* the `callback` function with `ipcRenderer`. Whenever the `event` is received, the `callback` will be executed. In essence, you could think of this as a function simply storing the `callback` in an internal variable, returning whenever the value has been set.

This is a core concept of asynchronous programming: Registering a callback with an event handler to be able to run code in parallel (the `callback` would be executed while the other code is idle, in your case). If I was to illustrate the code flow in your case, I would do it like so:

```js
const ipcRend = require('electron').ipcRenderer  // (1)
var savedData = null                             // (2)

ipcRend.on(                                      // (3)
    'channel',
    (event, data) => {                           // (5)
        savedData = data
        console.log(data)
        console.log(savedData)
    }
)

console.log(savedData)                           // (4)
```

First, your variable declarations (1) and (2) are executed. Then, (3), `ipcRend.on(...)` follows. And here's the catch: The next code being executed is (4), the call to `console.log ();` with the yet `null` variable `savedData`. Your anonymous callback function (the stuff inside the braces with `(event, data) => {}`), (5), is only executed once the event `"channel"` has been received. This can happen at any time, but most likely not exactly when you register this callback with `ipcRenderer`.

Thus, you could use a promise if you want to wait for the callback to run before executing any other code (read more about Promises on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)):

```js
const ipcRend = require('electron').ipcRenderer
var savedData = null

await new Promise ((reject, resolve) => {
    ipcRend.on(
        'channel',
        (event, data) => {
            savedData = data
            console.log(data)
            console.log(savedData)
            resolve ();
        }
    )
});

console.log(savedData)
```

This way, `console.log (savedData);` will only be executed after the callback function ran.

However, this is not only clunky, but also not exactly best practice. Since you're already dealing with asynchronous programming, it is best to call another function which takes the data you received *as an argument* instead of storing it in the global scope. This way is more comprehensible and easier to maintain over longer time:

```js
function processReceivedData (data) {
    console.log (data);
    // Anything else you want to do with this data...
}

const { ipcRenderer } = require ("electron");

ipcRenderer.on ("channel", (event, data) => { processData (data); });
```

See? Much cleaner, much more comprehensible, and no more global variables! Of course, sometimes global variables just are required. But then make sure that no synchronous code depends on variable values which will only be set after any asynchronous event occurred.

---

As a footnote: Using `{}` in declarations from imports like the one I used above automatically "unpack" the loaded module in the desired variables. This way, you'd have to write `ipcRenderer` whenever you want to use it (which is longer, I know), but using this method is less error prone since you don't have to do `require().<submodule you actually want>`. Also, you could unpack multiple submodules at once: `const { ipcRenderer, contextBridge } = require ("electron");` loads both modules at once and stores them in `ipcRenderer` and `contextBridge`.